# Step forward button in Blender (Redo)?

Tags: interface

When I pressed the undo button in object mode it somehow brought me waaaay back in my steps and I wanted to know if there was a shortcut to undo the undo? Or a step forward shortcut?

Comment: this makes pressing undo in BLENDER! a little more intuitive
https://youtu.be/zDejCFBsWvg

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To **Redo** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to get a list of your undo history. Handy, if you've gone overboard with **Undo**.

Answer (score 11):

**Since Einar explains how to get back, I'll explain why it happens.**

This happens when you make edits in one mode (let's say edit mode) and then you switch out and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. As far as Blender is concerned, you have not done any more changes in Object mode, so it goes back one step, skipping all the edit mode changes. You will need to go back into edit mode in order to go back and undo steps in your changes in future. For now, follow Naioai Studios suggestion of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to re-do or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to show the undo history.

Here is an illustration of what I was saying:

[image: Undo Illustration]

**These are the standard shortcuts:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is standard undo.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is standard re-do.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> shows undo history.